# sizing of fractions in limits

Tags: fractions, height

How can i write the fractions in 1) so the numerator and denominator have the same height as the non-fraction in 2)

I'm using:

```
$1.\; \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1}}$ $\frac{x^2}{x-2}$  \\

$2.\; \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}}$ $\tan(x+\pi/4)$  \\
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you looking for \displaystyle?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you split each line into two math groups?

Comment: Change `$1.\; \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1}}$ $\frac{x^2}{x-2}$` to `$1.\; \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1}}\frac{x^2}{x-2}$`.  (i.e. remove the two `$` in the middle).  Actually, you should do this for both 1 and 2 anyway :-)

Comment: ty, i had added it - what is the best way to add a small space between the limit and the fraction?

Comment: Note that `\displaystyle`, if used correctly, will have two effects: (i) the fraction term will be typeset differently and (ii) the argument of `\lim` will be placed below rather than to the lower-right of "lim".

Comment: avoid using `\displaystyle`, but note if you do use it it does not take an argument so the `{..}` you have it are just stopping the white space stretching or shrinking

Comment: also never use `\\ ` at the nd of a paragraph (presumably you get an underfull hbox warning about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but isn't well coded. Are you tring to do an enumeration of maths formulæ?

```
$1.\; \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2}{x-2}$  

$2.\; \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\tan(x+\pi/4)$
```

Comment: ty, i had added the $ $ for a small space - what is the best way to add a small space between the limit and the fraction? ty

Comment: Normally it is all taken care of by the system. If think it's as fine as you'd like, you may add a tin unbreakable space (`\,`) between the  limit and the fraction.

Comment: superb, tyvm works

Comment: `\displaystyle` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @David Carlisle; Yes. 'Tis  fixed. Actually, I didn't notice the O.P. used `\displaystyle` as a command. Thanks!